# Kotlin: how to pass a function with varying arguments as a parameter to other function

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, retrofit

So, I'm rewriting my app's code te be "clean" (separation of layers, following MVVM pattern recommended by Android Team)

Here I've got my simple Retrofit interface to communicate with my API

```
interface Api {

    @GET("comments")
    suspend fun getPlaceComments(@Query("placeId") placeId: String): Response<List<CommentResponse>>

    @POST("comments")
    suspend fun addPlaceComment(@Header("placeId") placeId: String, @Header("text") text: String): Response<Unit>

    @DELETE("comments")
    suspend fun deletePlaceComment(@Header("placeId") placeId: String): Response<Unit>
}
```

Just a simple CRUD.

Now, one layer up, I've got my SocialRepository. To avoid code repetition, I created generic method `callSafely` that takes a suspending API function and a placeId as its parameters.

```
class SocialRepository {
    private val client: Api = ApiClient.webservice

    private suspend fun <T> callSafely(
        apiMethod: suspend (placeId: String) -> Response<T>,
        placeId: String,
    ): T? {
        Log.d(TAG, "$apiMethod called safely")

        var response: Response<T>? = null

        try {
            response = apiMethod(placeId)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        if (response?.isSuccessful != true) {
            Log.w(TAG, "response.isSuccessful isn't true.")
        }

        return response?.body()
    }

    suspend fun getPlaceComments(placeId: String): List<CommentResponse>? {
        return callSafely(client::getPlaceComments, placeId)
    }

    suspend fun deletePlaceComment(placeId: String): Unit? {
        return callSafely(client::deletePlaceComment, placeId)
    }

    suspend fun addPlaceComment(placeId: String, text: String): Unit? {
        return callSafely(client::addPlaceComment, placeId, text) // HERE LIES THE PROBLEM
        // I can't pass additional data because the method signature won't match with what's defined in callSafely()
    }
}
```

Now, it works pretty well, of course I've got also my Activity and its ViewModel and the ViewModel calls a method in the repository etc. It doesn't matter.

What matters is that adding a place comment requires additional data, like, the actual text of the comment. Getting and deleting comments require only placeId, whereas when adding a comment, its content, its `text` is also required.
I've read that passing `vararg` functions is impossible in Kotlin. I also wouldn't like to clutter all the API methods with something like a `List of params` that will most of the time be empty and will just create confusion.

I can go the easy way and just copy the code of `callSafely` to `addPlaceComment` and alter it, but that's not what I'm looking for. I know how to solve the problem, but I don't know how to do it `the clean way`. In the future I might add some more endpoints requiring additional data (except `placeId`) and the problem will show up again.

What would you do in this situation? How to write it "the correct way"?

I'm not even sure how to properly express what I'm looking for, that's why this post's so rambling. Sorry for that in advance. I really hope you can help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "clean way" is very broad concept. Everything depends on your needs and there is no "The one good way of doing things".

In your particular case you have several options:

1) Typealiases

```
typealias ApiCall1<P, R> = suspend (P) -> Response<R>
typealias ApiCall2<P1, P2, R> = suspend (P1, P2) -> Response<R>

fun <P> callSafely(param: P, call: ApiCall1<P, YourResult>): YourResult
fun <P1, P2> callSafely(param1: P1, param2: P2, call: ApiCall2<P1, P2, YourResult>): YourResult
```

2) Varargs

```
fun callSafely(vararg params: String, call: suspend (arr: Array<String>) -> YourResult {
   ...
   call(*params) 
   ...
}
```

3) Lambdas **(preferable for your situation)**

No-one is forcing you to use method references. Use lambdas when you need it. But place the lambda as the last parameter for "cleaner" code.

```
private suspend fun <T> callSafely(
    placeId: String,
    apiMethod: suspend (placeId: String) -> Response<T>
): T?

suspend fun getPlaceComments(placeId: String): List<CommentResponse>? {
    return callSafely(placeId, client::getPlaceComments)
}

suspend fun deletePlaceComment(placeId: String): Unit? {
    return callSafely(placeId, client::deletePlaceComment)
}

suspend fun addPlaceComment(placeId: String, text: String): Unit? {
    return callSafely(placeId) { id -> client.addPlaceComment(id, text) }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I know *the* ideal solution doesn't exist but option 3 is exactly what I've looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class SocialRepository {
private val client: Api = ApiClient.webservice

private suspend fun <T> callSafely(
    apiMethod: suspend (placeId: String) -> Response<T>,
    vararg stringParams: String,
): T? {
    Log.d(TAG, "$apiMethod called safely")

    var response: Response<T>? = null

    try {
        response = apiMethod(stringParams[0])
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    if (response?.isSuccessful != true) {
        Log.w(TAG, "response.isSuccessful isn't true.")
    }

    return response?.body()
}

suspend fun getPlaceComments(placeId: String): List<CommentResponse>? {
    return callSafely(apiMethod= client::getPlaceComments, stringParams=*arrayOf(placeId))
}

suspend fun deletePlaceComment(placeId: String): Unit? {
    return callSafely(apiMethod=client::deletePlaceComment, stringParams=*arrayOf(placeId))
}

suspend fun addPlaceComment(placeId: String, text: String): Unit? {
    return callSafely(apiMethod = client::addPlaceComment,stringParams= *arrayOf(placeId,text))
}
```

}

Comment: don't just post code, if you just post code, nobody learns anything. explaining a solution could be just as useful as the actual solution, so consider adding some more explanations in future. just a friendly tip :)